# CertificateException: No name matching hostname found Maven

Tags: web-services, maven, maven-2, wsdl

I have an HTTPS WSDL URL (https://hostname/MyApp/MyApp.svc?wsdl) that needs to be consumed in a Maven project.  The certificate on WSDL is expired and is issued to hostname.company.com.

I have following code in Maven pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>                          
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>https://hostname/MyApp/MyApp.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>                           
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I do a clean and build, I get following error

```
[jaxws:wsimport]
Processing: https://hostname/MyApp/MyApp.svc?wsdl
jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, C:\WorkspaceNetBeans\Maven\WSTest\target\generated-sources\jaxws-wsimport, -d, C:\WorkspaceNetBeans\Maven\WSTest\target\classes, https://hostname/MyApp/MyApp.svc?wsdl]
parsing WSDL...

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching hostname found

Failed to read the WSDL document: https://hostname/MyApp/MyApp.svc?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>. 

failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

    Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

I added the certificate to keystore using keytool utility.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: I had a similar problem using Apache as LB for my services, if you are using Apache and Virtual-Hosts maybe your virtual-host dont match with name that maven is using. Try run maven with -Djavax.net.debug=SSL that can raise some tip about SSL errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can download your wsdl locally from web browser and then run wsimport on that local file to generate your Java model.

Comment: I tried that, but the WSDL file has various references to schemas (ex: https://hostname/MyApp/MyApp.svc?xsd=xsd2) and ended up getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You have the possible options:

1) Import the certificate of the server in to the Trust Store, also ensure that the CN name presented in the Server Certificate is same as the Hostname you are using. This link can be helpful:http://bluefoot.info/howtos/how-to-avoid-java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-name-matching-localhost-found/

2) Use a tool like Netbeans or eclipse which can ignore (I doubt it though) SSL aspects of the server.

3) Create a local version of the WSDL resolving all the dependent XSD references and use that WSDL.

Comment: Option 3 worked for me as suggested by you and @Eugene Kuleshov.  Is there a Maven way (inside pom.xml) to resolve this issue?